# How to add a group of integers

Tags: java

Can some one tell me how to do this and explain it to me:
 Write a program that reads a text file that contains groups of integers that start with the word “next”. For each group, the program computes and writes out the sum of integers in that group. There may be any number of groups.

I'm not asking you to do my home work, I need some one to explain it. I got stuck with the scanner

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? This is not a "do my homework" service.

Comment: Agreed.  Also, please tag homework questions as homework.  Don't try to sneak it.

Comment: Apologies to everyone, I was too quick in labeling this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560275/compute-the-sum-of-20-integers-from-a-file  The referenced question was in C language this one in java etc.   Never the less both are lousy questions :-(

Answer (score 1):

For the reading a text file bit, check out the [**Scanner**](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class, which can parse your text file. Or alternatively, use a [BufferedReader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) (Scanner will probably be much, much easier).

Since you have a variable number of groups, [ArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) can be useful for storing your groups of integers.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Agree on the homework warnings.

You will probably use a Scanner to read the file. Look at the javadoc for Scanner. There is also a method in Integer called parseInt which allows you to turn a string into an integer.